# ActiveMQ broker closing connection after 1000 messages sent in transaction

Tags: python, jms, activemq-classic, qpid

I have been trying to move son long-running processes from one application to another. The queues are implemented using qpid proton (AMQP 1.0), with the broker being hosted in AWS. An application sends a single message with a payload including a number of object ids that will be processed (in this case, inserted into a postgres database). An `unpacker` queue takes those ids, and in turn, sends a single message to a `saver` queue, that is listening to messages and stores the objects one by one. `unpacker` wraps those individual messages in a transaction, like so (loads of code removed for brevity):

```
 def send(self, transaction):
        # Get payload
        payload = transaction.packed_payload

        # Unpack messages
        unpacked_messages = self.unpack_data(payload)

        for message in unpacked_messages:
            proton_message = Message(body=message)
            transaction.send(self.sender, proton_message)

        transaction.commit()
```

And `saver`, like this:

```
def on_message(self, event):
    message_body = json.loads(event.message.body)

    # data saving logic here
```

This happens to work really well if there are 1000 or fewer objects in the packed transaction. However, for higher volumes (and that's certainly a production case) the transaction will apparently succeed on commit, but only 1000 messages will be processed, and the following error will appear:

`ERROR:proton:Could not process AMQP commands`

I have tried to bump `max_prefetch` and `constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy` to no avail, as it consistently shuts down connection on the 1000th message, on AWS and locally.

Am I missing something regarding ActiveMQ and its queue configurations? What could explain this behavior?

Comment: The information here is to vague to begin to guess at the problem.  Maybe ask the ActiveMQ users list for help and post some broker logs and a minimal working test driver that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim. Yes it is indeed vague as the whole setup can get quite a bit more complex, but probably the basic setup is there. I will try to reach out on the user list (probably worth trying the Proton one as well).

Comment: Also recommend you try using ActiveMQ Artemis which has a much more actively maintained AMQP stack